# Does bootstrap-vcpkg.bat affect anything outside the current directory?

Tags: windows, package-management, windows-packagemanagement

I've read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcpkg/get_started/get-started?pivots=shell-cmd for instructions how to set up and configure `vcpkg`.

**Does `bootstrap-vcpkg.bat` affect anything outside the current directory?**
Does it set environment variables, either within the current shell or persistent to future new shells?

I'd like to understand whether it is safe to install multiple instances `vcpkg` in different directories; therefore I'm wondering whether there's anything done by `bootstrap-vcpkg.bat` in the `vcpkg` from one directory that would affect the behavior of, or use of the `vcpkg` from another directory.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59396543/5437543) implies that each "instance" of `vcpkg` (separated by directories) is completely self-contained and does not affect behavior of, or use of `vcpkg` in a different directory. But that answer is answering a slightly different question, so I wanted to confirm here.